How to define congruent angles without geometric transformations or measures?
I'm trying to build a proof of triangle SAS congruence (see the existing proof I know of) that does not base on geometric transformations, but only on basic axioms and definitions.
Along my journey to find the way, I've read numerous books, and different books approach that thing from different points of view. Some prefer to take SAS congruence as an axiom (Hilbert's Axiom III.6 contains the major part of the proof), some try to prove it by translating one triangle to the other (Atanasyan and Pogorelov do that their ways in their 'Geometry 7-9' books), and some are unsure whether to prove it or not (see this topic here in MSE).
My idea of the desired proof is the following:
Definition 1: Two triangles are congruent if for each angle of one triangle there exists an equal angle in the other triangle, and the sides opposite to equal angles in these triangles are congruent.
Definition 2: (here lies the issue; I don't know how to define equal angles in terms of their sides and not their measures, without using overlaps, translations, or other kinds of geometric transformations).
I want to use the following as axioms:
Axiom 1: Each plane has collinear points and noncollinear points. Through two points passes one and only one line.
Axiom 2: Three points on a straight line are such that only one is between two others.
Axiom 3: Each line segment has a positive length. A length of a line segment is equal to the sum of lengths of its parts.
Axiom 4: Any straight line on a plane splits it into two half-planes.
Axiom 5: Each angle has a positive degree measure. A measure of a straight angle is equal to 180 degrees. A degree measure of an angle is equal to the sum of lengths of angles, on which it is split by any ray passing in between its sides.
Axiom 6: There is only one way to construct a line segment of a given length on a given ray from its vertex.
Axiom 7: There is only one way to construct an angle of a given measure less than 180 degrees from a given ray at a given half-plane.
Axiom 8: Through a point complanar with the given line, if the point is not on a given line, it is possible to construct only one line parallel to it.

There was a recent exchange on HMSE on SAS you may find interesting https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/what-is-the-origin-of-two-straight-lines-cannot-enclose-a-space-axiom-in-eucli

Euclid spends the first few theorems prepping for 1.4 (SAS) so that he can move lines and superpose two triangles, but the proof is essentially "look - they're the same if they lie on top". It might as well be axiomatic. Later authors patched that proof by specifying that two straight lines sharing endpoints can't enclose an area, but this new axiom is there mainly to enable SAS, so, again, it might as well be axiomatic. Good luck!
